# Can't get hgignore to work

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I'm trying to make mercurial ignore the "1.txt" file in win7, mercurial 2.3

Why is 1.txt still shown with the "hg status" command here?

```
\hgtest> dir


Directory: \hgtest


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        2012-08-27     11:01            .hg
-a---        2012-08-27     11:03         44 .hgignore
-a---        2012-08-27     11:02          6 1.txt


\hgtest> type .hgignore
syntax: glob
*.txt
\hgtest> hg status
? .hgignore
? 1.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is because your .hgignore  is in utf-16 encoding. Thereof the size 44 for a 22 character text.

hg probably don't understand the .hgignore file.

Try opening the file and save it in plain ANSI encoding.

Comment: Good catch.  That and/or it has BOM at the start -- Byte Order Marks don't belong at the start of text files Mercurial is expected to read.

Comment: I suspected an encoding problem, but I didn't go as far as UTF-16. I just tested this using the information in the original question and I can see the reported problem. I didn't even need a BOM; just setting the file encoding to UTF-16 was enough to prevent Mercurial from reading the .hgignore file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's still in the repository. Try to forget that file.
If you want to have this file in the repository, and at the same time ignore it, that it does not show, I think that this is not possible.

Comment: No I just created the repo, have not made any commits. Also it is shown with the ? in front, meaning it is not tracked right?

Comment: a question mark will be beside the name of the new file (unversioned one) (http://compsoc.ie/wiki/how_to:mercurial)

Comment: Yes but I'm expecting it to not show up because of the .hgignore

Comment: @Rikard: You're correct that a file marked with `?` is eligible for being hidden by `.hgignore`. Your `.hgignore` file looks correct to me so I don't know why `1.txt` is still shown as unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried recreating your scenario based on the information in your original question on 64-bit Windows 7, but with Mercurial 2.2.3 (I am using TortoiseHg 2.4.2) and I don't see this problem. I checked both in a cmd.exe console and a Powershell console (which is what you appear to be using). I noticed, that the reported size of the `.hgignore` file in my case was half of what it was in your original question. I am not sure what the difference in size is because of. Since we are on different versions of Mercurial, I wonder if something broke in 2.3.

Comment: I'm indeed using powershell, but I also tried in cmd as well with the same result. I did not use tortoiseHg at all.

Comment: @hlundvall has a reason for the difference in the size that I had noticed; could you check the encoding of your file and also for the presence of a BOM at the start?